# Nested attributes not being saved in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nested-forms, activemodel

I'm trying to create a nested form in Ruby on Rails. The form appears as expected. But when it is saved the nested attribute, Booking, is not saved.

#### cleaner.rb

```
class Cleaner < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name

  validates_presence_of :quality_score
  validates :quality_score, inclusion: 0.0...5.0

  has_many :assignments

  has_many :bookings

  has_many :cities, through: :assignments

  has_many :customers, through: :bookings
end
```

#### customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name
  validates_uniqueness_of :phone_number
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :cleaners, through: :bookings

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bookings
end
```

#### booking.rb

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :cleaner

  validates_presence_of :customer
  validates_presence_of :cleaner
  validates_presence_of :date
end
```

#### customers_controller.rb

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_customer, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

  def index
    @customers = Customer.all
  end

  def show; end

  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
  end

  def edit; end

  def create
    @customer = Customer.find_or_initialize_by(phone_number: params[:phone_number])
    @customer.assign_attributes(customer_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.update(customer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @customer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to customers_url, notice: 'Customer was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def set_customer
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :city, :city_id, bookings_attributes: %i[cleaner_id date])
  end
end
```

#### HomeController.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @customer = Customer.new
    @customer.bookings.build
  end
end
```

#### Parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"c4xo2M4r57+/xBsmcc+7yajpQU13u1kiwmOthx/nP7HiJXJIfS9/OqC0MrWCcaDrSW/xN8UGk2+LVfnUnbTb3A==", "customer"=>{"first_name"=>"adfad", "last_name"=>"fad", "phone_number"=>"9392323", "city_id"=>"1", "bookings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"cleaner_id"=>"1"}}}, "#<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007f86bec96480>"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2017", "date(2i)"=>"8", "date(3i)"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Create Customer"}
```

#### updated form

```
<h1>Sign Up Now</h1>

<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
  <% if @customer.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@customer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this customer from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone_number %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :city %><br>
    <%= f.select :city_id, options_for_select(City.pluck(:name, :id)) %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :bookings do |b| %>
    <%= b.date_select :date %>
    <br>
    <%= b.select :cleaner_id, Cleaner.all.pluck(:first_name, :id) %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It's now failing with 2 errors

```
Bookings customer can't be blank
Bookings date can't be blank
```

Comment: my i ask why there is an id in bookings_attributes? in your params?

Comment: @wiwit I'm not sure. Probably shouldn't be.

Comment: id for book? if yes you dont need that its automatic for rails

Comment: in your view where did you get the <%= f.text_field :first_name %> there is no loop?

Comment: @wiwit the form is just a snippet of the complete thing.

Comment: try to use tail -f log/develoment.log to youre console if you send the parameters right :)

Comment: try to create first in your console to test your model if your accepted attribute working right then its 100% sure the problem is in your controller

Comment: What are your params look like when you submit the form?

Comment: you should avoid as much as possible nested_attributes, and use instead fields_for just as @wiwit showned you

Comment: that sounds good you got unprocessable entity you create a good validation that serve you right. look at bookings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"cleaner"=>"1"}}},

Comment: it seems the problem is in the view in your bookings_attributes params you pass a 0 id? or value 0? for cleaner?

Comment: @wiwit If you look at the updated params, cleaner_id is set to 1

Comment: let me see the customer_params in your Customer controller

Comment: bookings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"cleaner"=>"1"}} in this params your not passing a date thats why rails said you got Bookings date can't be blank

Comment: @wiwit I was able to fix the date. But it's still saying customer is blank

Comment: let me see your params in your customer controller

Comment: in your last post i see this   bookings_attributes: %i[id cleaner customer date]) remove the id and the customer

Comment: I've already done that. It looks like `%i[cleaner_id customer_id date]`

Comment: `Processing by CustomersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tBtMubbumnBSPqJltYmMNGFbMiomrJbm5VNQrqhs/dAlslYpBeoC9U1Oi/ZGN5cWgN2CUJQRXKusZQT9Kj8ZvQ==", "customer"=>{"first_name"=>"James", "last_name"=>"Jones", "phone_number"=>"8328823424", "city_id"=>"1", "bookings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2017", "date(2i)"=>"8", "date(3i)"=>"4", "cleaner_id"=>"1"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Customer"}`

Comment: in your  booking.rb model change this has_many :bookings , validiate: false

Comment: hope it works cross finger :)

Comment: @wiwit Do you mean customers.rb?

Comment: @AntarrByrd yes cusotmer.rb not booking.rb im sorry

Comment: It worked. Thanks @wiwit

Comment: YEHEY!!! lol my i see your whole customers_controller.rb

Comment: @wiwit I've updated it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the iteration of the first @customer so rails can read properly
i saw this example https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

```
 <%= f.fields_for :booking do |ff| %>  
 <%= ff.select :city_id,options_for_select(City.pluck(:name, :id)) %>
```

i hope it works *cross finger* :)

Comment: The city is an attribute on the customer, not the booking. For booking, I need the customer, cleaner and date. Although the cleaner will be assigned in a before_save callback.